# ComboBox Binding TextBlock Text to value DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have many **comboboxes** with different **DisplayMemberPathes**

I need create the one style with TextWrapping

App.xaml:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >  
            <Setter.Value>
                 <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding *what here?*}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
```

ComboBoxes:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="val1" />
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="val2" />
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="val3" />
```

So, I know, that I can create the property Value in each ComboBoxItem class and use it

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value }" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

But may be there is another way without create special property?

Comment: What are you binding to? A collection of strings?

Comment: different items, it may be collection of strings, collection of keyvalyepair,collection of classes etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding to a value type, such as a `string` or an `int`, you can simply use `{Binding}`, here's an example:

```
<DataTemplate >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This kind of binding will bind to the **object itself** as opposed to a **Property** on said object.

**Note**: What gets displayed in the `Text` will be whatever gets returned by the `.ToString()` method on that object.

You could then override the `.ToString()` method in your classes to return something useful back, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

This will force `MyClass` to be displayed as whatever is inside the `Name` property in your `ComboBox`.

---

Taking this a step further, your requirements are that you may need to put objects of different types in a single `ComboBox`. Not a problem, you can make use of the `DataType` property in a `DataTemplate`, see below:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:myClass}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Note that these should be declared in a `ResourceDictionary`, and will affect **all** objects that are displayed of that type. This allows you to define what gets displayed for a given type.

Comment: thank you for  override string ToString(), and I do not need to put objects of different types in a single ComboBox =) but thank you for this too, may be sometime it helps

Comment: but...what about dictionary like a source? Dictionary<int, string> for example

Comment: You can't define a `DataTemplate` for a `KeyValuePair` because it contains generics so that's out of the question. I would say you're better off using a concrete class instead, this way you can override to `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you cannot set both `DisplayMemberPath` property and a specific ItemTemplate at the same time. They are mutually exclusive.

You can read it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This property [i.e. DisplayMemberPath] is a simple way to define a default template that describes how to display the data objects

So if you need a specific item template, simply do not set the DisplayMemberPath property of your combobox (there is no need to do it).

Comment: I know it, so I asked how to create ItemTemplate to work for different DisplayMemberPath aka instead different DisplayMemberPath

Comment: In this case I guess that the best solution is the one that @MikeEason proposed. Alternatively you can use an [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) too.